# How to keep comma between tags in _form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, tags, acts-as-taggable-on

For some reason my commas keep disappearing whenever I go to edit the _form, which means if I resubmit the _form now all the tags in that _form are combined into one big, ugly tag :/

I have this line in my _form `<%= f.text_field :tag_list %>`

I closely followed this railscast tutorial: [railscasts.com](http://railscasts.com/episodes/382-tagging?view=asciicast)

Can anyone figure out off hand what might be the problem here? I don't even know what other code to add here that would be helpful.

Please let me know if you need further explanation or code to help you help me :-]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this .......

```
<%= f.text_field :tag_list,  :id => "tags", :value => @your_var.tags.map(&:name).join(',') %>
```

Hope, I understand the question correctly and this solution will help you.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, just use `join(', ')` on your `tag_list` :)

Comment: Hey Jason! Is there a special way to format that? I tried `<%= f.text_field :tag_list.join(', ') %>` but that gave `undefined method 'join' for :tag_list:Symbol`. I use this in the show page, maybe you can pull a lesson from it that I'm missing since it seems to be a similar idea: `<%= raw @goal.tag_list.map { |t| link_to t.titleize, tag_path(t), class: deadline_label_class(@goal) }.join(' ') %>`

Comment: Hi Anthony! It's because `:tag_list` is a symbol, as indicated by the error. It has no method `join` :) Just a heads up, those that start with a `:` is a symbol like `:name`, `:age`, etc. You just need to call map.join in the `class` with the `tag_list`. i.e. `your_class.tag_list.map{|tags| [Enter how you want to format your tags]] }.join(', ')`

Comment: Thanks for the added explanation Jason :) I had a little struggle still, which I could have figured out, but I took the lazy route and went with the other answer :/ I gave you a check tho & on a few of your previous answers :)